# как сделать чтобы человек с определённым именем мог пользоваться командой добавлять удалять

Tags: python

Дан код интернет магазина, где можно покупать товары ,задача заключается в том что при входе нужно спросить какое имя и если имя admin,то выдать права владения(добавлять и удалять товары)

Код:

```
money = 1000
bag = []
shop = [ ["макароны",100], ["гречка",88], ["мясо",500], ["лемон",200] ]
print("Добро пожаловать в наш магазин.Как вас зовут")
name = input()
if name == 'admin':
    print("дать функции владения")
    shop.remove(input())
    shop.append(input())
else:
    print("Добро пожаловатьв магазин")
```

Comment: "-кто там? -я! -проходите". В интернете много примеров с тем как делается аутентификация

Comment: money = 1000
bag = []

shop = [
        ["макароны",100],
        ["гречка",88],
        ["мясо",500],
        ["лемон",200]
      ]

print("Добро пожаловать в наш магазин.Как вас зовут")
name = input()
if name == 'admin':
    print("дать функции владения")
    shop.remove(input())
    shop.append(input())
else:
    print("Добро пожаловатьв магазин")

Answer (score 3):

Если это делать так же простенько как у вас в примере, то можете попробовать вот так. Соответственно, если вы введете "admin", затем "добавить", то сможете добавлять "товары". Но "по взрослому" это делается, конечно, не так.

```
money = 1000
bag = []
shop = [ ["макароны",100], ["гречка",88], ["мясо",500], ["лемон",200] ]
print("Добро пожаловать в наш магазин.Как вас зовут")
name = input()

if name == 'admin':
    print("Вы вошли как админ")
    while True:
        command = input()
        if command == 'добавить':
            product = input('Укажите товар') 
            price = input('Укажите стоимость')
            shop.append([product,price])

            print('Текущий список товаров')
            print(shop)
else:
    print("Вы вошли как гость")
```